# Group by grouped column?

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table of node likes, which looks roughly like this:

```
lid nid uid type
1   23  3   like
2   23  1   like
3   49  3   dislike
4   11  6   like
```

lid = unique ID for this table, nid = "node" (content) ID, uid = user ID and type is self explanatory.

With this query:

```
SELECT nid, COUNT(lid) AS score, type
FROM node_likes
INNER JOIN users ON node_likes.uid = users.uid
GROUP BY nid, type
```

I can get each node with its like and dislike scores. The inner join is irrelevant; some (dis)likes are from users that no longer exist, and the join is to eliminate them.

The result looks like this:

```
nid score type
307 4     like
307 1     dislike
404 24    like
```

How can I then sub-group this query by `type`, and return the top-scoring node ID for each "like" type (like/dislike)?

Ie.

```
nid score type
404 24    like
307 1     dislike
```

Comment: ORDER BY score DESC will give you the top nid's. I'm not sure what you mean by sub-group...

Comment: ORDER BY score DESC will return the highest scores, regardless of type. I want it to return the highest scores of each type.

Comment: confuse, should not the top score for both like/dislike goes to nid=404?

Comment: Very sorry ajreal, I'd typed the result set wrong. My fault!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(nid ORDER BY likes DESC),',',1) as most_likes_nid,
    MAX(likes) as most_likes,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(nid ORDER BY dislikes DESC),',',1) as most_dislikes_nid,
    MAX(dislikes) as most_dislikes
FROM (
    SELECT 
        nid,
        COUNT(IF(type = 'like', 1, null)) as likes,
        COUNT(IF(type = 'dislike', 1 ,null)) as dislikes
    FROM node_likes
    GROUP BY nid 
) as t
```

Comment: it concatenates all the nid's in the right order and then gets the first one

Comment: On second thoughts, it does seem a *little* hacky, but it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT nid, COUNT(lid) AS score, type
    FROM node_likes
    INNER JOIN users ON node_likes.uid = users.uid
    GROUP BY nid, type        
    ORDER BY type DESC, score DESC;
```

may do the trick.

Comment: That orders by score and type, but doesn't remove the extraneous results from the middle. That's to say, if there are posts that don't have the top "like" rating, but have more likes than the top "dislike" nid, they'll appear above the top "dislike" nid regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    nid, max(score) as score, type
FROM (
    SELECT nid, COUNT(lid) AS score, type
    FROM node_likes
    INNER JOIN users ON node_likes.uid = users.uid
    GROUP BY nid, type
) results
GROUP BY type
ORDER BY type DESC, score DESC
```

Comment: That's very strange. It returns the highest scores, but the nids somehow become associated wrongly.

Comment: It is not strange at all. That is why i added the SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT...)) hacks in my solution.

Comment: @Vatev You are right. Alternatively, my query needs another condition to find the `nid` for the `max(score)` association.